# Shoud I import the css directly into the html of a certain view?

Tags: html, css, import, frontend, coding-style

I've been working in this personal project, in which there are multiple HTML(views) and CSS files. o far I've been importing all the CSS files into one `global.css`, and importing this `global.css` into my index.html, some friends of mine are now contributing in this project, and a lot of conflicts are happening regarding the style of the page, some styling from one view are affecting another views, so I thought that maybe the problem could be solved by importing the CSS files directly into the HTML(view). Example: in a login view(login.html) would be directly imported the `login.css`.
Is there any disadvantage in importing the CSS files like that or maybe a better solution?

Opinions about the possible solution that I've exemplified or a new solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, I highly recommend that you use a framework for your styling, such as (bootstrap or Foundation). That will give you a solid ground to start with. Second, I assume you are familiar with the three ways you can implement your style with css(external, internal, inline). With that being said, I think it is better to separate your files.
PS: keep track of your IDs and classes, and use comments as much as you need.